# Clear console for each run of Testacular/Karma + Jasmine

Tags: console, jasmine, karma-runner

It is difficult for me to catch with the eye a boundary between test runs.

Is it possible to clear console for each run of Testacular/Karma + Jasmine or at least put there something easily catched by the eye, for example a series of newlines?

**Note**

Currently it is an abandoned question because I am no longer trying to perform tasks described in it. Please do not ask for additional info. Write only if you know for sure what to do. It will help other people.

Comment: In what OS are you developing? If you are using Grunt to build your project, or if you have considered using it, then I believe [grunt-exec](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-exec) could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own reporter, and do whatever you want with it.

Also, if you're on a Mac and use Growl, take a look at [karma-growl-reporter](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-growl-reporter)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to fully understand your need but [karma-spec-reporter](https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter) can give you a detailed review of your test execution. Output example from [karma-spec-reporter-example](https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter-example):

```
array:
    push:
      PASSED  - should add an element
      PASSED  - should remove an element
      FAILED  - should do magic (this test will fail)       expected [] to include 'magic'
        at /home/michael/development/codecentric/karma-spec-reporter-example/node_modules/chai/chai.js:401
        ...
PhantomJS 1.8.1 (Linux): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.086 secs / NaN secs)
```

Comment: I want to delete all the trash from previous testing session so it wouldn't lead me astray.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a reporter available for this: https://github.com/arthurc/karma-clear-screen-reporter

It's working for me on OSX.